# How to run external script silently and retrieve its exit code bash

Tags: bash

Hello I have some script which returns lots of messages for both good and bad executions but the only thing I'm interested in is its exit code. I've tried something like this:

```
output=`somescript.sh 2>&1` # which actually silents this script
echo &? # actually this always returns 0. Probably because output variable is set...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a typo, but did you mean `echo $?`?

Answer (score 3):

```
somescript.sh 2&> /dev/null
echo $?
```

Here `2&>` redirects both the output and error to `/dev/null`

the exit status is held by `$?` variable

`/dev/null` acts like a *black box*

Comment: Ok I've failed with testing that tbh ;) That is correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
somescript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
echo $?
```